# How to scp using "Safeguard for Privileged Passwords" string

Tags: scp

I want to copy file to the server with address target_ip. And I have Safeguard system which generates hostname string like `vaultaddress=11.34.5.123@token=EyUusdfsdfEFEFDSCDFVfXEqFsdcsdcsdPe3s@username@target_ip@11.21.0.104`.

How can I make the scp command (request)?

If I make it like this:

```
scp vaultaddress=11.34.5.123@token=EyUusdfsdfEFEFDSCDFVfXEqFsdcsdcsdPe3s@username@target_ip@11.21.0.104 file target_ip:/var/test
```

it fails on Connection timed out.